# Comments have vanished

Tags: support

I was having a discussion with someone in the comments section of a question I have asked, clarifying parts of their answer: [Name clash with sys.sysusers system view in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632840/name-clash-with-sys-sysusers-system-view-in-sql-server)

However, now both their answer and the associated comments have disappeared.  The answer was posted about 10 minutes earlier, and we had had a couple of comments each, and then they just vanished about a minute or two after the latest comment.

What's more, the notifications have vanished from my inbox and they are no longer showing in my list of comments.

It is like they never existed!

I didn't take a note of the responder's name, so I can't contact them via other channels to see what happened.  As far as I can see there was nothing in the answer nor comments that warrant their removal.

Was this deliberate, or is it a site error?  No explanation has been given, so if it is deliberate, as a new user it is very, very disorientating!  I have spent 10 minutes clearing caches and checking my other interactions to see if they have also vanished.

Comment: the answer would have been deleted. when it's deleted all comments under it are deleted aswell

Comment: If that is truly the case, then this is perhaps a feature request, rather than a support question: to provide some feedback that this has happened, rather than everything just vanishing, everywhere.  However, why would someone delete an answer that was constructive and leading towards a solution?

Comment: The answer was deleted by OP after he realized that it didn't work.

Comment: @HappyDog an answer can be deleted for a number of reasons. the OP deleted it themselves, it was voted to be deleted by the community (3 users), a mod removed it, it was automatically removed due to spam/offensive flags. only users with 10k in rep or mods can see deleted answers while the OP of the answer can see their own deleted answer (but not others until they get 10k)

Comment: I guess the point is that it should say 'comment deleted' or something, so that people don't think they're going mad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer was deleted by its author as apparently it did not relate to the question (version mismatch). All comments and corresponding notification disappear in this case. When you have 10K+ reputation you can see such deleted question (mainly for moderation purposes).

Image of the conversation:

[image]

Comment: This was a bad judgement call on behalf of the OP.  As I mentioned, we are using multiple different versions of SQL Server, and in fact we are trying to implement a fix that will run on multiple versions, including 2008 which is the last one to run on Windows XP.  The answer was helpful, and was usefully contributing, so deleting it seems to be a mistake.  In particular, the second paragraph is probably the correct solution, though I need to investigate that a bit more before I can be sure.

Comment: @HappyDog you should edit your SO question so Mark's answer is applicable if it is the case.  I'll ping Mark Cidade so they aware of this thread.

Comment: I deleted it because I made a wrong assumption about the table name. I was testing with `syslanguages` instead of `sysusers` (see my last comment in the image).

Comment: OK - That makes more sense why it was deleted.  Thanks for clarifying.